# basic mean reversion in horse racing

Tags: probability

Horse trainer X is guaranteed to win 10 races from 100 starts every racing season.(12 months)
After 3 months, Horse trainer X has won only 1 race from 25 starts.
How do i calculate a number that represents the strength of the mean-reverting probability at the 26th start?
Is there an online calculator that can do this?

Comment: Who guarantees this? If the trainer losses $90$ races in a row, will the sport fix the next $10$ results to ensure the trainer wins them?

Comment: It's a hypothetically speaking obviously.

Comment: What does it matter whom guarantees what? At the end of the day it's the numbers that matter.If you can't do the calc why bother?

Comment: It matters because mean reversion is an effect seen when the future is typically  independent of the past; the position where it is negatively correlated to it is rather different. Clearly there is a difference between the probability of winning the next race being $\dfrac{10}{100}=0.1$ and it being $\dfrac{10-1}{100-25}=0.12$.

Comment: Thanks, i came up with 25/1.5 =16.66 = 2.77 just playing around on my calculator. I have zero maths education obviously.

Comment: Reversion to the Mean
Reversion to the mean, also called regression to the mean, is the statistical phenomenon stating that the greater the deviation of a random variate from its mean, the greater the probability that the next measured variate will deviate less far. In other words, an extreme event is likely to be followed by a less extreme event.

Comment: Indeed it is.  So if the probability of winning each future race is $\dfrac1{10}$ then then the proportion of future races won is likely to be higher than the past record of $\frac{1}{25}$

Comment: I disagree with your comment "mean reversion is an effect seen when the future is typically independent of the past". Horse trainers, staff and stakeholders rely on prize money, which makes mean reversion all the more stronger. I consider the question unanswered.

Comment: You might look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_toward_the_mean), including *"Statistical regression toward the mean is not a causal phenomenon. A student with the worst score on the test on the first day will not necessarily increase his score substantially on the second day due to the effect. On average, the worst scorers improve, but that is only true because the worst scorers are more likely to have been unlucky than lucky. To the extent that a score is determined randomly, or that a score has random variation or error..., the phenomenon will have an effect."*

Comment: Thanks for that Henry but it seems unrelated to horse racing. Trainers and jockeys need to maintain their strike rates in order to remain relevant. Horses go through different levels of fitness/form during a campaign.